# Как работает SHOW INDEX FROM?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

```
$q = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM just");
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять как работает и что возвращает SHOW INDEX FROM.

Comment: А вам это зачем именно в таком виде? Обычно такие команды не в коде выполняют, а в mysql-клиенте, либо каком-нить PMA. Или у вас продвинутая система миграции изменений в структуру БД? Т.е. по существующим индексам определяются те, которые необходимо добавить/удалить?

Comment: @BOPOH тоесть я не смогу увидеть массив значений в браузере?

Comment: Почему не сможете? Сможете, точно так же как и с [любой другой выборкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Мне просто стало интересно где это может пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вывести в окно браузера вот так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM user");
$output = "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))       
{   
    $output .= "<tr><td>". $row['Key_name'] 
            . "</td><td>". $row['Column_name'] 
            ."</td></tr>";      
}   
$output .= "</table>";  
echo $output;
```

Возвращает ресурс. Если вставить

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM user");
var_dump($result);
```

то получите тип `resource(4) of type (mysql result)`